# Java - Detection collision in 2D tile game

Tags: java, collision

I'm having fun to build a 2D tile game (without Slick2D of libgdx) and I'm working on collision since  more than 15 hours. I think it's time to ask question. I searched a lot but none really responds what I searched for.

So, this is what it look like : [2D game capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATHFE.png) (The dark tile are were the player can't walking in) and [Another 2D game capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgS21.png)

The rectangle are were collision can happen. There, when they collide, it's still moving just enough to be lock in the tile. (can't do nothing anymore)

So, my class is called by the input handler, the update and the draw. Theses three by the "play" class. Who just update stuff. (Player.MoveUp(), Player.draw, ...)

- The "WorldManager" is where the tiles are managed (the only 4 of them and the getType() is to look up if it's blocked (0 valid and 1 blocked)
- The "LevelGeneration" is where level, position of tiles and their ID is
  mapped (with a int[][]) (he is ok' it create map with ID and when I
  show then they are all good).
- The AssetManager is where I cut sprites sheets to transform then in BufferedImage
- The tilesize is 50 and the player is 41x36.
- I have a problem since I want to have a liberty of mouvements (4 sides to make 8 mouvements sides ) and the anchor point seem to be at upperleft side

So here is my class (without imports and packages):

```
public class Player {

public static double SPEED;
public static int WIDTH, HEIGHT;
public static float XPos, YPos;
public static float destXPos, destYPos;

public static BufferedImage presentImage;
public static int[] position; 
public static boolean moving;
public static boolean movementlock;
public static int side; // 0 up 1 right 2 down 3 left
public static Rectangle p = null;
public static Rectangle e = null;
private static boolean mouvementlock;
private static boolean collision;

public static void CreateHero(){
    // Valeurs de test
    position = new int[2];
    SPEED = 1;
    XPos = destXPos = 100;
    YPos = destYPos =  100;
    presentImage = AssetManager.Player[0][0];
    moving = false;
    movementlock = false;
    collision = false;

    position[0] = (int) (XPos/WorldManager.TileSize);
    position[1] = (int) (YPos/WorldManager.TileSize);

}

public static void MoveUp(){
    side = 0;
    destYPos -= SPEED;
    moving = ValidateNextPosition();
}
public static void MoveRight(){
    side = 1;
    destXPos += SPEED;
    moving = ValidateNextPosition();
}

public static void MoveDown(){
    side = 2;
    destYPos += SPEED;
    moving = ValidateNextPosition();
}

public static void MoveLeft(){
    side = 3;
    destXPos -= SPEED;
    moving = ValidateNextPosition();
}

static void updateMovement(){
    if(moving == true && mouvementlock == false){
        mouvementlock = true;
        System.out.println("Mouvement");
        System.out.println("X : " + XPos);
        System.out.println("Y : " + YPos);
        XPos = destXPos;
        YPos = destYPos;
        System.out.println("Xdest : " + destXPos);
        System.out.println("Ydest : " +  destYPos);
        System.out.println("" + moving);
        moving = false;
        mouvementlock = false;}
    else{
        destXPos = XPos;
        destYPos = YPos;
    }
}


public static boolean ValidateNextPosition(){
    if(moving) return false;
    if(collision) return false;

    p = new Rectangle((int) XPos, (int) YPos, presentImage.getWidth(null),presentImage.getHeight(null));
    int tileid = 0;
    boolean validate = true;
    int destpos[] = new int[2];
    double TileCollision[] =  new double[2];
    destpos[0] = (int) destXPos/WorldManager.TileSize;
    destpos[1] = (int) destYPos/WorldManager.TileSize;
    TileCollision[0] = 0;
    TileCollision[1] = 0;


    if(side == 0 && collision != true){
        if(destpos[1] - 1 > 0){
            tileid = LevelGenerator.getIdmap()[destpos[0]][destpos[1] - 1];
            if(destYPos + 1 < 0 || WorldManager.Tuiles[tileid].getType() == 1 ){
                destpos[1] -= 1;collision = true;}}
    }
    if(side == 1 && collision != true){
        tileid = LevelGenerator.getIdmap()[destpos[0] + 1][destpos[1]];
        if(destXPos + 1 < 0 || WorldManager.Tuiles[tileid].getType() == 1 ){
            destpos[0] += 1;collision = true;}
    }
    if(side == 2 && collision != true){
        tileid = LevelGenerator.getIdmap()[destpos[0]][destpos[1] + 1];
        if(destYPos - 1 < 0 || WorldManager.Tuiles[tileid].getType() == 1 ){
            destpos[1] += 1;collision = true;}
    }
    if(side == 3 && collision != true){
        tileid = LevelGenerator.getIdmap()[destpos[0]][destpos[1]];
        if(destXPos - 1 < 0 || WorldManager.Tuiles[tileid].getType() == 1 ){
            /*destpos[0] -= 1*/;collision = true;}
    }
    if (collision == true){
        TileCollision[0] = LevelGenerator.getPosmap()[destpos[0]][destpos[1]][0];
        TileCollision[1] = LevelGenerator.getPosmap()[destpos[0]][destpos[1]][1];
        e = new Rectangle((int) TileCollision[0], (int) TileCollision[1],WorldManager.TileSize,WorldManager.TileSize);}

    if(e != null && p.intersects(e)){
        validate = false;
        System.out.println("collision");}

    return validate;
}


public static void update() {
    updateMovement();
}

public static void draw(Graphics2D g) {
    g.drawImage(presentImage,(int) XPos,(int) YPos,presentImage.getWidth(null),presentImage.getWidth(null),null);
    if(p != null){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(p.x, p.y, p.width, p.height);}
    if(e != null){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(e.x, e.y, e.width, e.height);}
    }

}
```

To resume,

1. The collision happen too late and the player get stuck in the blocked block.
2. Sometimes it pass through it since the (I suppose) the top left don't hit the block.
3. It can go out of the map without problems and then it crashed, but everything I tried keep crashing the game

Thank you very much and have a nice day

Hell'no

(P.S. : English is my third language, so ask me if you don't completely understand)

Comment: why do you want us to fix your game?? why dont you pick an issue and concentrate on it it s all a mess

Answer (score 0):

When `collision` gets set to true and your `ValidateNextPosition` method returns false, `collision` (and by extension your `moving` variable) can never be toggled again because of your `if(collision) return false` statement at the top.

Comment: Hi, I just try and the player get stuck in the wall again.  Do you have another suggestion ?